# Integral of product of normal PDFs

Tags: probability, statistics

How can I simplify the expression $\int_a^b \phi(2x) \cdot \phi(x) dx$?

Where $\phi$ is the standard normal probability density function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are basically integrating $\exp(-\frac12x^2)\exp(-2x^2)=\exp(-\frac52 x^2)$, which you can write in terms of $\Phi$ or similar.

Comment: Thank you for that